# Reach for the deep nested element using Selenium WebDriver (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I looked through a lot of topics on Stackoverflow and tried several recommendations but could hardly succeed in resolving my particular case. I'm trying to automate [Google Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) using Selenium WebDriver + Java. I need insert the Number of instances (the first input area on the page) using Java code.

My Java code is following:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator");

    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//iframe[contains (@name, 'goog_')]")));

    WebElement document = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains (@name, 'goog_')]"));
    var iframe = document.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='myFrame']"));
    var input = iframe.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='input_66']"));
    input.click();
    input.sendKeys("4");
```

But NoSuchElementException is thrown when I launch the code: "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe[@id='myFrame']"}.

`Xpath` is correct but this element is hidden deep into `html` tree. How can I reach for the element (Number of instances) in this particular case? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to switch to the parent iframe element, then switch into the inner iframe and only after that try accessing the input element.
I see you tried to locate the iframe elements but you do not switch into them.
Try this:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator");

//Find and switch to outer iframe
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'product')]")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'product')]")));

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='myFrame']")));

WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='input_66']"));
input.click();
input.sendKeys("4");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! `switchTo()` is what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try with the below line of code?**

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator");

    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//iframe[contains (@name, 'goog_')]")));

    WebElement document = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains (@name, 'goog_')]"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(document).switchTo().frame("myFrame");
    
    
    //var iframe = document.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='myFrame']"));
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='input_66']"));
    
    ele.click();
    ele.sendKeys("4");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is also correct. `.switchTo()` was my Achilles' heel (missing element) :)